# Django .html want to access selected option within html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a .html page which should show leaderboards. At the moment my code shows all leaderboard for the different categories (Explorer, Evaluator, Commentator, etc.) at the same time. The information for these leaderboards is stored in the context variable, which is passed to the .html page through the .view file in the background. My code for the page looks like the following:

```
{% include "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <select name="select">
    {% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
        {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
            <option value="{{category}}">{{category}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>


<table class='table'>
    {% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
        {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
            <tr><td> {{category}} </td></tr>
            {% for name, points in userDictionary.items %}
                <tr><td>{{name}}</td><td>{{points}}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to be able to display a specific leaderboard. Let's say the user chooses 'Evaluator' from the drop-down option field. Then this should be displayed. How can I find out which option is selected within the .html file and display the respective information?

It would already help me a lot if I would know how I could do for example:

```
if optionvalue = "Evaluator" make <p> Hello there you have chosen Evaluator </p>
```

I know that is not really a good example, but that's what I am trying to do in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you potentially do something like in this fiddle?

https://jsfiddle.net/kq2d4x2n/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').on('change', function(){
    var choice = $('#test').val();
    $('.banner').html('You chose' + ' ' + choice);
        $('.' + choice +'').show();
    });
});
```

Get the value from the dropdown when selected then show the table with a corresponding class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example using jQuery. 
Whenever a uses selects a value, it creates an `alert`. Run the code below to see it in action.

```html
<select name="select">
    <option value="">Choose a value</option>
    <option value="">-----------------------</option>
    <option value="Evaluator">Evaluator</option>
    <option value="Commentator">Commentator</option>
    <option value="Explorer">Explorer</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('select[name=select]').on('change', function() {
    var chosen_val = $(this).val();
    if (chosen_val) {
        alert('Hey there you have selected ' + chosen_val);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay I see how I can make the alert. That's totally understandable. My problem is: How can I alter the content of the 'table class'. The table should be different depending on what was chosen in the drop down. So do I need to write html in the JQuery function? At the moment I really don't see how I can do this --- making an alert is one thing, but altering the table (which is in html) when selecting something is totally different (at least to me).

Comment: @Dante I just gave you something to get started. With the help of docs and some other answers on SO, you should be able to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okidoki! Will try my best and post my solution as soon as I achieved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the hints. With your help I figured it out. Nevertheless, for all others who are looking for the solution, this is my implementation and it works. Although I am not sure, if I am using pure JavaScript or if it is a mixture of Javascript and JQuery....
My select:

```
<select name="leaderboardOptions" id="leaderboardOptions">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
{% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
    {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
    <option value="{{category}}">{{category}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

My Javascript Function?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#leaderboardOptions').on('change', function(){
var choice = $('#leaderboardOptions').val();
var choiceArray = new Array();
var availableOptions = document.getElementById('leaderboardOptions').options;
for(i = 0; i < availableOptions.length; i++){
    choiceArray.push(availableOptions[i].value);
}
for(i = 0; i < choiceArray.length; i++){
    if(choiceArray[i] === choice){
        $('.' + choiceArray[i] +'').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.' + choiceArray[i] +'').hide();
    }
}
});
});
</script>
```

And here two tables as example (I have many more....still wondering if it would be possible in an even more dynamic way...)

```
<div class="Explorer" style="display:none">
<table class='table'>
{% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
    {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
        {% if category == "Explorer" %}
            <tr><td> {{category}} </td></tr>
            {% for name, points in userDictionary.items %}
                <tr><td>{{name}}</td><td>{{points}}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>

<div class="Evaluator" style="display:none">
<table class='table'>
{% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
    {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
        {% if category == "Evaluator" %}
            <tr><td> {{category}} </td></tr>
            {% for name, points in userDictionary.items %}
                <tr><td>{{name}}</td><td>{{points}}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

And what I forgot in the beginning --> INSERT in your html or your head_css.html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```